# javascript Intl.numberFormat mask textfield

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm trying to use Intl.NumberFormat
to format my currency values ​​in a text field with the following code:

but i got this on key up event:

```js
function formatCurrency(input) {
  // appends $ to value, validates decimal side
  // and puts cursor back in right position.

  // get input value
  var input_val = input.value;
  let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat([], {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL'
  })
  input.value = formatter.format(input_val);

}

(function initalize() {
  // IIFE method
  let input = document.querySelector("input[data-type='currency']")
  input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    formatCurrency(e.target);
  })
})();
```

```html
          <div class="input_renda">
            <h3 class="textfield_label">
              value
            </h3>
            <div class="material-textfield">
              <input type="text" name="currency-field" id="currency-field" value="" data-type="currency"
                placeholder=" R$ 1,000,000.00" />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I posted the snippet when I type in my input it does not update the formatted value and is only with NAN

Comment: when i type text i get number i wanted to allow only numbers